# WPF DataGrid - Cell Styling Based on Complex DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, datatable

My "Application" has a DataGrid that has as its source a DataTable. The DataTable is populated with objects like the following:

```
public class DataWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public String Value { get; set {...} } // Changes fire PropertyChangeEvent
    public bool IsMinimized { get; set {...} } // Changes fire PropertyChangeEvent

    // Other code to implement INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

The general idea here is that `Value` property can either be in a "fully" minimized form or not, and we can check to see if it is by looking at the `IsMinimized` property, which is set elsewhere.

When the user modifies a cell in the DataGrid, the change to `Value` executes a check that determines if the value is minimized or not, which then set the `IsMinimized` property, which in turn fires a `PropertyChanged` event. I'd like to have the styling on each cell outline the cell with yellow if `IsMinimized` is `False`, and have no outline otherwise.

I've been able to get the initial yellow outline to happen, but when the `Value` property is modified I can't get the binding to refresh. I attribute this to the fact that the I'm dealing with a `DataRowView` within the bindings. For reference, here is a snippet of the cell style:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="GridCellStyle">         
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">                        
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />                                
                        </Grid>                        
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>                    
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>       
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource CellIsMinimizedConverter}}" Value="False" />                     
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />                    
            </DataTrigger>                
        </Style.Triggers>                        
    </Style>
```

The converter `CellIsMinimizedConverter` is being used to pull the `IsMinimized` property for the current column based on the `DataRowView`, but I'm not sure how to get a change to the `IsMinimized` property to get this to trigger.

**Notes:**
I can't use validation rules as it's OK for users to enter a non-minimized value.

Comment: A DataTrigger without a Value for comparison is somehow useless, isn't it? ;)

Comment: True. This was a typo in my post rather than what is in the actual source code. I've corrected it.